# JTree enlarges width when a node gets expanded

Tags: java, swing, width, jtree, expand

I've got a real hard problem with a JTree.

I've implemented a JTree with a selfwritten Model (wich is extended from TreeModel).

```
    fileSystemModel = new MyModel(new File(directory));
    fileTree = new JTree(fileSystemModel);
    fileTree.setEditable(true);
    fileTree.setDragEnabled(true);
    fileTree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {

        public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent event) {
            File file = (File) fileTree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
        }
    });
```

So i added it to a JPanel and this JPanel to a JFrame.

No i got this Problem: I start the Frame, and if i expand a single Node, the width of JTree is going to enlarge to the width which is needed to show the leafs.

I tried to set this:

```
fileTree.setMaximumSize(width, height);
```

But it failed and i also tried to embedd the JTree into JScrollPanel with a Maximum-Size, and this has also failed.

The JTree is still adjusting its width how many it needs.

So i tried now for two days and doesn't find anything, so i would be apprecciate if someone of you could help me.

Thanks!

Comment: I have to embedd this JPanel into a JSplitPane

Comment: I have to embedd this JPanel into a JSplitPane, which has a GridBagLayout. I tried now to start a Default JFrame and only embedd my JPanel and it works. But it doesn't work in the Frame with JSplitPane...

Comment: never-ever use any of the setXXSize - they do more harm than help even at their best ;-) Randomly piling LayoutManager above LayoutManager without understanding their behaviour isn't exactly effective (as you noticed :-) That said, a JTree in a JScrollPane shouldn't make the scrollPane increase its size (because the scrollPane is a validationRoot), but simply show scrollBars as needed. For more help sooner, please show a small (!) runnable example demonstrating the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect described is characteristic of the default `FlowLayout` of `JPanel`. You can see the change when you click on the left panel is this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822810/how-does-one-make-a-component-in-the-center-of-a-borderlayout-occupy-all-center/5824318#5824318).

Addendum: As seen in the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822810/how-does-one-make-a-component-in-the-center-of-a-borderlayout-occupy-all-center/5824318#5824318), `GridLayout` allows the component to expand; it works particularly well with `setVisibleRowCount()` followed by `pack()`.

Comment: Excuse me, could you tell me how you fixed your problem? Because I use a BorderLayout and insert the JTree at WEST, but I've your same problem and that's a bit ugly.

Comment: @user2896152: Benni hasn't been seen in a while; respond here if you post a new question that relies on the [example cited](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822810/how-does-one-make-a-component-in-the-center-of-a-borderlayout-occupy-all-center/5824318#5824318).

Comment: I created another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377017/jtree-changes-width-when-nodes-are-expanded