# Expanded JTree Rendering

Tags: java, swing, jtree, cellrenderer

When the tree is expanded and I tried to rename the tree node not all the name displayed only about 4 5 letters and the others as (...) but if the tree is collapsed, every thing is OK. The following is my custom tree cell render:

```
public class customTreeCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree,
        Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded,
        boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus){

        super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value,
        selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
        JLabel label = (JLabel) this ;


        label.setSize(label.getHeight(),value.toString().length());
        label.setText(value.toString());
        label.repaint();
        tree.revalidate();
        this.repaint();
        System.out.println("expanded "+expanded);
        System.out.println("Custom  "+ value.toString());

        return label;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. What is your question?  2. For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822810/how-does-one-make-a-component-in-the-center-of-a-borderlayout-occupy-all-center/5824318#5824318).

Comment: Welcome to this forum :-)  For successful participation please a) learn java naming conventions and stick to them b) never-ever call setSize in application code c) never-ever trigger a repaint/revalidation in the painting cycle. In fact, never-ever change any state of the target in getXXRendererComp d) learn about renderer/editor concepts

Comment: as to the problem: it's a LAF and version dependent caching quirk - have seen it comming and going without ever nailing a robust fix ...

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> label.setSize(label.getHeight(),value.toString().length());
> ```

1. This method takes width and height, you switched both parameters.
2. String.length() returns only the letter count, not the display size of the string. If you want to get the width of the string rendered with the font of the DefaultRenderer, use `getFont().getStringBounds("yourString", getFontMetrics(getFont()).getFontRenderContext()).getWidth();`

You can try this:

```
  if (label.getGraphics() != null) {
    final Rectangle2D r = getGraphics().getFontMetrics(getFont())
        .getStringBounds(value.toString(), getGraphics());

    final Dimension d = new Dimension((int) r.getWidth()
        + getIcon().getIconWidth() + getIconTextGap(), (int) r.getHeight());

    label.setMaximumSize(d);
    label.setPreferredSize(d);
    label.setMinimumSize(d);
  }
```